# Error JSON.parse

Tags: spring, angular

Люди добрые, помогите. Пытаюсь заняться склейкой Angular и Spring. При добавлении джойнов перестали работать некоторые вещи и в браузере получаю такую ошибку:

```
error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token } in JSON at position 117599 at 
JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad 
(http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:68453:51) at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask 
(http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3396:35) at Object.onInvokeTask 
(http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:45212:33) at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask 
(http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3395:40) at Zone.runTask 
(http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3164:51) at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as 
invoke] (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3477:38) at invokeTask 
(http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:4618:18) at 
XMLHttpRequest.globalZoneAwareCallback 
(http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:4655:25)
message: "Unexpected token } in JSON at position 117599"
```

Проблемы появились после добавления классов в backend. Объясните пожалуйста, где эту ошибку искать то? Я в ангуляре не ориентируюсь ещё, нужно поконкретнее, если можно. Спасибо.

Employee модель

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employees")
public class Employee implements java.io.Serializable {
@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;

@Column(name = "firstname", unique = true)
private String firstName;

@Column(name = "lastname")
private String lastName;

@Column(name = "email")
private String emailId;

@Column(name = "positionId")
private long positionId;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "positionId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
private EmployeePosition employeePosition;
```

Position модель

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employeePositions")
public class EmployeePosition implements java.io.Serializable{
@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;

@Column(name = "position")
private String position;

@OneToMany(targetEntity = Employee.class,
        mappedBy = "positionId",
        orphanRemoval = false,
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<Employee> employees;
```

Квери контроллер

```
    @RestController
    public class JoinQueryController {
    private final JoinQueryService joinQueryService;

    public JoinQueryController(JoinQueryService joinQueryService) {
        this.joinQueryService = joinQueryService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/dept/employees/left")
    public ResponseEntity<List<EmployeeAndPositionDto>> 
getEmployeAndPositionLeftJoin(){
        return new ResponseEntity<List<EmployeeAndPositionDto>> 
 (joinQueryService.getEmployeAndPositionLeftJoin(),
                HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    @GetMapping("/dept/employees/right")
    public ResponseEntity<List<EmployeeAndPositionDto>> 
getEmployeAndPositionRightJoin(){
        return new ResponseEntity<List<EmployeeAndPositionDto>> 
 (joinQueryService.getEmployeAndPositionRightJoin(),
                HttpStatus.OK);
    }


}
```

Репозиторий

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeePositionRepository extends 
JpaRepository<EmployeePosition, Long> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT new 
backend.dto.EmployeeAndPositionDto(d.position, e.firstName, e.lastName, 
e.emailId) " +
            "FROM EmployeePosition d LEFT JOIN d.employees e")
    List<EmployeeAndPositionDto> fetchEmpPosDataLeftJoin();

    @Query(value = "SELECT new backend.dto.EmployeeAndPositionDto( 
e.firstName, e.lastName, e.emailId, d.position) " +
            "FROM EmployeePosition d RIGHT JOIN d.employees e")
    List<EmployeeAndPositionDto> fetchEmpPosDataRightJoin();
}
```

ДТО

```
public class EmployeeAndPositionDto {
private String empFirstName;
private String empLastName;
private String empEmail;
private String empPosition;

public EmployeeAndPositionDto(String empFirstName, String empLastName, 
String empEmail, String empPosition ){
    this.empFirstName = empFirstName;
    this.empLastName = empLastName;
    this.empEmail = empEmail;
    this.empPosition = empPosition;
}
```

Comment: Ответ где-то в коде. Вас устроит?

Comment: А как мы должны ответить на ваш вопрос? Поймите чтобы вам помочь мы должны что то увидеть. Пока только то что не хватает }

Comment: Я  не имею представления где искать и что показать. Весь код выкладывать смысла нет. И если есть возможность не тратить время на сарказм, то было бы здорово узнать, что реально показать нужно.

Comment: Про скобку я догадался. Я не понимаю где этот JSON.рarse искать, позицию 117599.